# Magento2: How to get free shipping product details on cart page?

Tags: magento2, free-shipping

How to get free shipping product details on cart page?

I have added some product under the cart price rule and set free shipping condition.

I need to display free shipping promotion message on the cart page. Message should be showing only which free shipping product rules apply.

Magento 2.x

Comment: On which location you want to show this message ?

Comment: Hi Pawan, I want to display the message on the cart page.

Comment: @Pawan Message should be showing only which free shipping product rules apply.